# HK2 annotations not being handled

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm using HK2 through Jersey, and am looking to get @Immediate services working.  In the process, I notice that (as it seems) none of the annotations for my services are getting registered.  E.g., after spinning up my ServiceLocator and looking at my descriptor for a service annotated with @Singleton, it is still set as @PerLookup.  My code for initiating my application handler is below:

```
ApplicationHandler handler = new ApplicationHandler(resourceConfig, new AbstractBinder() { ... });
```

My binder registers a service like so:

```
bindAsContract(ShouldHaveSingletonScope.class);
```

Looking at my ServiceLocator immediately after this, I see that the scope is not being pulled from the class (still @PerLookup).  Is there something additional I need to specify to tell HK2 to parse class annotations?  This seems like a pretty standard use case so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method on ServiceLocatorUtilities called [addClasses](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b01/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#addClasses%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

So get access to the ServiceLocator and just do

```
ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(locator, ShouldHaveSingletonScope.class);
```

The binders are very literal, and will only do what you tell it as opposed to looking at the classes directly.

Comment: Looks like this method does indeed honor the class annotations through DynamicConfiguration, where registering a class in a Binder does not.  This seems very counterintuitive and frustratingly limiting.  Especially, given the fact that ApplicationHandler accepts a custom Binder as a parameter.  Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: It would be a good idea to enter a Jira asking for a bind method, perhaps, like "analyze(Class<?> clazz...)" on the binder for cases such as yours

Comment: What is locator variable? where do I init it from?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
bindAsContract(ShouldHaveSingletonScope.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

You can either configure the locator manually using Binder

-or-

use hk2 annotations, run `hk2-inhabitants-generator` (see [hk2 doc](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b01/inhabitant-generator.html)) which will generate `META-INF/hk2-locator/default` file, then you will need to create your own `ComponentProvider` (see [jersey doc](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)) to populate service locator from that.

Comment: So, this means that HK2 can't pull annotations directly off the class?  Whats the point of annotating the class then?

Comment: That has been my frustration as well.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35191749/2163960